# Find and count adjacent array's elements in a 2D array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, minesweeper

so im working on a function or a solution for this problem but im still a junior.
this is the provided array, [javascript]
**

```
[ 
  [0, 9, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 9, 0],
  [0, 9, 0, 9],
  [9, 9, 0, 0],
  ]
```

new

```
  [1, 9, 2, 1],
  [2, 3, 9, 2],
  [3, 9, 4, 9],
  [9, 9, 3, 1],
]
**
```

im starting a minesweeper project, the zeros are empty spaces , the 9's are mines, i need to change the zeros to the number of adjacent mines, i couldnt find a simple solution that i could understand , so if someone can provide a simple solution i would appreciate it.
i thought about getting the  coordinates
`[x-1][y-1], [x][y-1] [x] [y+1]` 
etc.. for each index but the thing is not every index has these coordinates. help plz

Comment: please explain briefly. So we can get a clear view of a problem.

Comment: is that clearer @Mu

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go to all `8` positions (`pos`) below snippet and need to check if they are in scope of correct index(because they can go below `0` and more than `3` as per your 2-d array).

```js
const arr = [
  [0, 9, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 9, 0],
  [0, 9, 0, 9],
  [9, 9, 0, 0],
];

const pos = [
  [-1, -1],
  [-1, 0],
  [-1, 1],
  [0, -1],
  [0, 1],
  [1, -1],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
];

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  result.push([]);
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; ++j) {
    if (arr[i][j] === 0) {
      let count = 0;

      pos.forEach(([x, y]) => {
        const newX = i + x;
        const newY = j + y;
        if (
          newX >= 0 &&
          newY >= 0 &&
          newX < arr[i].length &&
          newY < arr.length
        ) {
          // console.log(newX, newY, arr[newX][newY]);
          if (arr[newX][newY] && arr[newX][newY] === 9) ++count;
        }
      });
      result[i][j] = count;
    } else {
      result[i][j] = arr[i][j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```